# iOS simulator: terminate all apps from terminal

Tags: ios, terminal, ios-simulator

I need to terminate all running applications in iOS simulator using **terminal/script**, any ideas ?

Please don't tell me to use gestures or CTRL + H,  I need that in terminal.

Comment: According to this medium article - https://medium.com/xcblog/simctl-control-ios-simulators-from-command-line-78b9006a20dc - it ahould be fairly simple using `xcrun simctl`. I’m posting this as a comment since I’m unable to rest/verify this at the moment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the this command to terminate an app on simulator:

```
xcrun simctl terminate <device> <application identifier>
```

Example:

```
xcrun simctl terminate "iPhone 8 Plus" com.myapps.app
```

If you know the application identifiers for all the apps running, you can easily iterate through the app identifiers in a script and terminate each app:

```
#!/bin/bash
array=( com.myapps.app1 com.myapps.app2 com.myapps.app3 )
for i in "${array[@]}"
do
    xcrun simctl terminate "iPhone 8 Plus" $i
done
```

If you want the script to be simulator-agnostic, you can use this command to get all available simulators and terminate the app in each simulator.

```
xcrun simctl list
```

A good article on simulator commands:

https://medium.com/xcblog/simctl-control-ios-simulators-from-command-line-78b9006a20dc